# MultiPage print with Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing issues showing page nos while printing multiple multipage reports

**below is the sample HTML Format :**

```css
<style type="text/css"> body {
  counter-reset: report 1 page 0;
}
td.footer:after {
  counter-increment: page;
  content: "Page " counter(page)" of Report " counter(report);
}
.rowLabel3 {
  counter-reset: page 0;
  counter-increment: report
}
</style>
```

```html
<table>
  <thead style="display: table-header-group;">
    <tr>
      <th>Report Specific Header Contents which needs to come on every page we are displaying report</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="display: table-row-group;">
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot style="display: table-footer-group;">
    <tr>
      <td class="footer">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<div class="rowLabel3" style="page-break-after:always;">*** END OF REPORT ***</div>

<table>
  <thead style="display: table-header-group;">
    <tr>
      <th>Report Specific Header Contents which needs to come on every page we are displaying report</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="display: table-row-group;">
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot style="display: table-footer-group;">
    <tr>
      <td class="footer">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<div class="rowLabel3" style="page-break-after:always;">*** END OF REPORT ***</div>​
```

Here , when Tfoot appear on each page It does not actually increment the section.

If this approach is correct what I have tried is also count the no of rows and then added extra row after 40 rows and add a page break with Page nos. But that is not consistent across different reports.

Comment: Why you use `@page` ? when i use `body` it s works

Answer (score 0):

It's work like this :

```
body {
    counter-reset: report 1 page 0 ;
}

td.footer:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of Report "  counter(report);
}
.rowLabel3{
  counter-reset: page 1;  
  counter-increment: report
}
```

i just change `@page` and rename

Comment: Thanks for your help  , I tried the above suggestion and updated the post accordingly with html that actually look like , but some how the page no does not increase , What I am expecting as Table Footer class is table-footer-group, as soon as Page will break tfoot will be painted on the bottom and my td have class as footer which will increase the page.